# Modify dns cache with Win32 API on windows(no host file)

Tags: c++, dns

I need to modify dns cache, for example, redirect www.microsoft.com to 111.222.333.444. Not by modifying the etc/hosts file.

I see **ipconfig /displaydns** is outputting the dns cache, and it's maintained by a service named "Dns Client", can I modify the cache?

google says there is an API **DnsModifyRecordsInSet** that does this job, and an example from sdk: `Microsoft SDK_\Samples\netds\DNS\ModifyRecords` , I tried the example but it complains error code 9005/9004/9002/9009 for different website, here's the command line:

```
test.exe -n www.microsoft.com -t A -l 360 -d 127.0.0.1
Failed to add the host record for www.microsoft.com and the error is 9004

test.exe -n www.bing.com -t A -l 360 -d 127.0.0.1
Failed to add the host record for www.bing.com and the error is 9009

test.exe -n www.test.com -t A -l 360 -d 127.0.0.1
Failed to add the host record for www.test.com and the error is 9002
....
```

here's the code:

```
#include <windows.h>  //windows
#include <windns.h>   //DNS api's
#include <stdio.h>    //standard i/o
#include <winsock.h>  //winsock

#define BUFFER_LEN 255

//Usage of the program
void Usage(char *progname) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Usage\n%s -n [OwnerName] - t [Type] -l [Ttl] -d [Data] -s [DnsServerIp]\n",
            progname);
    fprintf(stderr,"Where:\n\tOwnerName is the owner field to be added\n");
    fprintf(stderr,"\tType is the type of resource record to be added A or CNAME\n");
    fprintf(stderr,"\tData is the data corresponding to RR to be added\n"); 
    fprintf(stderr,"\tTtl is the time to live value in seconds \n");
    fprintf(stderr,"\tDnsServerIp is the ipaddress of DNS server (in dotted decimal notation)\n");
    exit(1);
}

//  the main function 
void __cdecl main(int argc, char *argv[])

{

    DNS_STATUS status;               // return value of  DnsModifyRecordsInSet() function.
    PDNS_RECORD pmyDnsRecord = NULL; //pointer to DNS_RECORD structure
    PIP4_ARRAY pSrvList = NULL;      //pinter to IP4_ARRAY structure
    LPTSTR pOwnerName = NULL, pNameData = NULL;  //owner name and the data for CNAME resource record
    char HostipAddress[BUFFER_LEN];         //Ip address required to add host record
    char DnsServIp[BUFFER_LEN];             //DNS server ip address

    memset(HostipAddress, 0, sizeof(HostipAddress) );
    memset(DnsServIp, 0, sizeof(DnsServIp) );


    //Allocate memory for DNS_RECORD structure.

    pmyDnsRecord = (PDNS_RECORD) LocalAlloc( LPTR, sizeof( DNS_RECORD ) );

    if (!pmyDnsRecord) {
        printf("Memory allocaltion failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (argc > 8) {

        for (int i = 1; i < argc ; i++) {

            if ( (argv[i][0] == '-') || (argv[i][0] == '/') ) {

                switch (tolower(argv[i][1])) {

                case 'n':
                    pOwnerName = argv[++i];
                    pmyDnsRecord->pName = pOwnerName; //copy the Owner name information 
                    break;

                case 't':
                    if (!_stricmp(argv[i+1], "A") )
                        pmyDnsRecord->wType = DNS_TYPE_A; //add host records
                    else if (!_stricmp(argv[i+1], "CNAME") )
                        pmyDnsRecord->wType = DNS_TYPE_CNAME; //add CNAME records
                    else
                        Usage(argv[0]);
                    i++;
                    break;

                case 'l':
                    pmyDnsRecord->dwTtl = atoi(argv[++i]); // time to live value in seconds
                    break;
                case 'd':
                    if (pmyDnsRecord->wType == DNS_TYPE_A) {
                        pmyDnsRecord->wDataLength = sizeof(DNS_A_DATA); //data structure for A records
                        strncpy(HostipAddress, argv[++i], sizeof(HostipAddress)-1);
                        HostipAddress[sizeof(HostipAddress)-1] = '\0';
                        pmyDnsRecord->Data.A.IpAddress = inet_addr(HostipAddress); //convert string to proper address
                        if ( pmyDnsRecord->Data.A.IpAddress == INADDR_NONE ) {
                            printf("Invalid IP address in A record data \n");
                            Usage(argv[0]);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                        pmyDnsRecord->wDataLength = sizeof(DNS_PTR_DATA); //data structure for CNAME records
                        pNameData = argv[++i];
                        pmyDnsRecord->Data.Cname.pNameHost = pNameData;
                        break;
                    }
                case 's':
                    // Allocate memory for IP4_ARRAY structure
                    pSrvList = (PIP4_ARRAY) LocalAlloc(LPTR,sizeof(IP4_ARRAY));
                    if (!pSrvList) {
                        printf("Memory allocation failed \n");
                        exit(1);
                    }
                    if (argv[++i]) {
                        strncpy(DnsServIp,argv[i],sizeof(DnsServIp)-1);
                        DnsServIp[sizeof(DnsServIp)-1] = '\0';
                        pSrvList->AddrCount = 1;
                        pSrvList->AddrArray[0] = inet_addr(DnsServIp); //DNS server IP address
                        if ( pSrvList->AddrArray[0] == INADDR_NONE ) {
                            printf("Invalid DNS server IP address\n");
                            Usage(argv[0]);
                        }
                        break; 
                    }
                default:
                    Usage(argv[0]);
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
                Usage(argv[0]);
        }   
    } else {
        Usage(argv[0]);
    }
    // Calling function DNSModifyRecordsInSet_A to add Host or CNAME records    

    status = DnsModifyRecordsInSet_A(pmyDnsRecord,                     //pointer to DNS_RECORD
                                     NULL,                      
                                     DNS_UPDATE_SECURITY_USE_DEFAULT,  //do not attempt secure dynamic updates
                                     NULL,                             //use default credentials
                                     pSrvList,                         //contains DNS server IP address
                                     NULL);                            //reserved for future use

    if (status) {
        if (pmyDnsRecord->wType == DNS_TYPE_A)
            printf("Failed to add the host record for %s and the error is %d \n", pOwnerName, status);
        else
            printf("Failed to add the Cname record for %s and the error is %d \n", pOwnerName, status);
    }
    else {
        if (pmyDnsRecord->wType == DNS_TYPE_A)
            printf("Successfully added the host record for %s \n", pOwnerName);
        else
            printf("Successfully added the Cname record for %s \n", pOwnerName);
    }           

    LocalFree(pmyDnsRecord); // Free the memory allocated for DNS_RECORD structure
    LocalFree(pSrvList);     // Free the memory allocated for IP4_ARRAY structure
}
```

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you look up the error values against Winerror.h?

Comment: I can see the '#define DNS_ERROR_RCODE_SERVER_FAILURE   9002L',  but what's wrong with the code or my usage? Why is SERVER_FAILURE(9002), NOT_IMPLEMENTED(9004), REFUSED(9005), NOTAUTH(9009)?

Comment: Reading the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682012%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) implies to me that this API is for requesting a DNS change on the authoritative DNS server, not the local DNS cache, which is why you're getting things like refused, not authorised, not implemented, server failure, etc. for DNS servers that you're not in control of.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any API that can be used to modify/add/delete local dns cache? I see dnsapi.dll exports lots of function, but I can't find any document about them.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. It would strike me as the sort of thing that would require at least administrative permissions, to avoid malicious use

Comment: I have admin permissions, but I can't use the hosts file for some reason.